# Как на JS проверить внутри цикла существует ли картинка с тем же названием что элемент массива

Tags: javascript

Есть массив элементов например:

```
var arrayOfItems = ['item1','item2','item3'];
```

И есть картинки в той же папке что и файл с JS-скриптом. Названия картинок совпадают с названиями элементов массива, но не все элементы имеют картинки. Предположим в папке есть картинки **item1.jpg** и **item2.jpg** но нету картинки **item3.jpg**. Нужно перебрать массив элементов через цикл и внести в новый массив div-блоки с названиями элементов первого массива и их картинками, но если под какой то элемент нету картинки тогда нужно избежать ошибки ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND и внести в таком случае в новый массив div-блок без тега "пустой" картинки.

Т.е. сейчас есть код:

```
<button onclick="test();">CLICK</button>
<div id="test"></div>
<script>
function test() {
    var arrayOfItems = ['item1','item2','item3'];
    var newArray = [];
    for(i = 0; i < arrayOfItems.length; i++) {
        var itemName = arrayOfItems[i];
        newArray.push('<div>'+itemName+'<img src="'+itemName+'.jpg"></div>');
    }
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = newArray;
}
</script>
```

А нужно что то типа:

```
function test() {
    var arrayOfItems = ['item1','item2','item3'];
    var newArray = [];
    for(i = 0; i < arrayOfItems.length; i++) {
        var itemName = arrayOfItems[i];
        if(...) { // если картинка с названием элемента существует
            newArray.push('<div>'+itemName+'<img src="'+itemName+'.jpg"></div>');
        } else {
            newArray.push('<div>'+itemName+'</div>');
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = newArray;
}
```

Нашёл вот такое решение:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = itemName;
img.onload = function() {
    ...
};
img.onerror = function() {
    ...
};
```

Но не могу его внедрить или не знаю как правильно. Пробовал так:

```
function checkImg(itemName) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = itemName+'.jpg';
    var result = 'true';
    img.onerror = function() {
        var result = 'false';
    };
    return result;
}
function test() {
    var arrayOfItems = ['item1','item2','item3'];
    var newArray = [];
    for(i = 0; i < arrayOfItems.length; i++) {
        var itemName = arrayOfItems[i];
        var result = checkImg(itemName);
        if(result == 'true') {
            newArray.push('<div>'+itemName+'<img src="'+itemName+'.jpg"></div>');
        } else {
            newArray.push('<div>'+itemName+'</div>');
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = newArray;
}
```

Но результат на странице тот же: "пустая" картинка под item3 и `ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

Есть ли какое то решение данной проблемы?

Comment: var result = 'false'; будет приравнен к true. 'false' это не boolean a string. Уберите ковычки

Comment: @Den, в цикле я проверяю именно строку а не boolean

Comment: `document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = newArray;` незя так. Можно вместо `newArray.push` делать `innerHTML += '<img src="'+arrayOfItems[i]+'.jpg">`

Comment: Сори туплю маленько

Comment: @Doofy, `innerHTML +=` все равно проблемы не решает

Comment: a newArray так и остался массивом или в строку переделали?

Comment: Разве это важно. Проблема в том что внутри цикла если например добавлю `console.log(checkImg(itemName));` то в консоле почему то вижу ТРИ `true` а не два `true` и один `false`

Comment: checkImg() создаёт новую картинку и возврашяет "true" не дожидаясь загрузки картинки? Там полезный колбак есть onload, попробуйте оттуда вернуть.

Comment: Выяснил что как раз `onload` и `onerror` внутри функции `checkImg()` почему то не работают

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41104/discussion-between-den-and-stckvrw).

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div class='images'></div>
```

```js
div = document.querySelector('.images');

var images = ['pic1', 'pic2', 'pic3'];
getImages(images, function(image) {
    div.innerHTML += '<div>' + image + '</div>';
});

function getImages(images, load) {
    images.forEach(function(image, i) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = image + '.jpg';
        img.onload = function() { load(img.outerHTML); }
        img.onerror = function() { load('<img>'); }
    });
}
```

Comment: @stckvrw, обновил. Так нужно? У меня одна картинка загружена, остальные пустые, ошибок нет

Comment: @stckvrw, от ошибки в консоли никуда не деться

Comment: @Grundy, если только не вернуть тег без ссылки, друг мой :)

Comment: @stckvrw, одна картинка из трёх в папке у меня. Видимо твой браузер на `img.onload` ругается. У меня Opera 38, консоль молчит. Может я ошибаюсь и браузер ругается на пустой тег img

Comment: @Doofy, ошибка все равно будет, если сервер по запросу вернет 404 статус, либо любой другой. То есть **в консоль** ошибка выведется.

Comment: Верно подметил Grundy. Потому что хоть картинка тянется из корневой папки, она будет иметь ссылку `http://localhost/pic1.jpg`. Насчёт `file:///C:/...` не знаю

Comment: @Doofy, спасибо тебе за решение, но у меня прописан уже большой цикл типа `for(i = 0; i < arrayOfItems.length; i++)`, там уже много всего поэтому чтобы не переписывать все на forEach() вопрос: смог бы ты еще написать решение но внутри цикла `for(i = 0 ...)` ?

Comment: @stckvrw, forEach работает по той же схеме в данном случае. `arrayOfItems[i]` это всё равно что `image`, есть также итератор `i`. Тут же проще, не надо объявлять переменную `itemName`. Можно просто image заменить на itemName